# Azure Dev Ops - How can we build code on one agent then deploy it to all agents for test automation code

Tags: maven, automation, ado

We currently have an internal team at our company that handles most of our CI/CD. Our automation framework runs through Jenkins using the internal team's applications. They handle the build and deploy to all the VMs with one application and then schedule the runs through another application. We are moving our automation into ADO as we want more control of it. We have it up and running but would like to optimize it better.

With our current setup, we have multiple agents and when we kick off a new set of tests the jobs are sent to the agents just fine. Each agent runs a new build then kicks off the test assigned to it. The problem is that the first test that runs on each agent takes a few minutes longer due to the build needing to be run before the test starts. I am new to ADO but I am sure there is a way to kick off the build on one agent and then deploy it to all the agents so only the individual tests are run on each.

We are using JAVA with Maven, Selenium, and Cucumber.

Sample of our yaml to build/run:

```
- job: Job_${{test}}
        timeoutInMinutes: 240
        displayName: Agent job group_${{test}}
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: Maven@3
            retryCountOnTaskFailure: 2
            displayName: Maven test ${{test}}
            inputs:
              mavenPOMFile: pom.xml
              goals: clean test -Dtest=${{parameters.serverJob}} -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@${{test}} -Denv=${{parameters.environment}} "-Dtester=$(Build.RequestedFor)"
            enabled: true
```